# Ubuntu Installer cannot see windows os partition and sees my hard drive as blank?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

Good day,
I have just downloaded ubuntu 12.10 today using windows 7 and installed it to my SD card. I booted up using the sdcard, and everything was going perfectly well until Ubuntu said i currently have no operating systems. So instead, I tried the 'Something Else' option, but it said that my hard drive is blank. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of installing to an SD card before that's an interesting idea but it could also be your problem, I would recommend installing the .iso to a USB [also called a pendrive] with at least close to a gig of free space [it's easer if it's empty but that's not mandatory] you can find some software for doing this at [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) [[YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) is my favourite] also make sure if you have a 64bit computer you download the 64bit .iso . Some computers [mine included] do not work well with the 32bit version [64bit does not work at all on 32bit computers!]

Good Luck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The symptom of a blank hard disk is most often caused by one of two conditions:

- **A partition table error** -- Overlapping partitions, ambiguous GPT/MBR status, partitions too big for the disk, and other problems cause libparted (upon which most Linux partitioning tools are based) to flake out. A common symptom is a disk that appears to be empty. My [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program (included in the Ubuntu `gdisk` package, IIRC) can fix many of these problems.
- **Leftover RAID data** -- A disk that used to be used in a motherboard-based software RAID configuration may have leftover RAID data that will confuse the system. You can usually remove this data by typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` (substituting the disk device filename for `/dev/sda`, if necessary). You must be *sure* that the disk is no longer used in a RAID configuration before you do this, though. You might also want to check your motherboard's firmware settings to be sure that RAID support is *disabled*.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is only one primary disk drive using any partitioning tools.If more than one primary drive is found convert it into logical drive. Don't change the windows drive to logical. There will be no problem in converting primary to logical, i.e, no data loss. I used Easeus Partition Master to do it and done it successfully.